# HTML 5 "number" type input has no value when typing a decimal place

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm writing a hybrid mobile app that uses HTML 5 number fields to show the correct keyboard. The app has a screen where values update in real-time that allow decimal places.

To be clear, decimal places work, and can be typed in - **that is *not* the problem.**

The app is written in AngularJS, I've tried getting the value both with jqLite directly from the element, and using the assigned scope value via ng-model.

This is how it behaves:

- Enter `1`, value is `1`
- Enter `2`, value is `12`
- Enter `3`, value is `123`
- Enter `.`, value is `undefined` according to Angular, and `""` when getting value directly.
- Enter `4`, value is `123.4`
- Enter `5`, value is `123.45`

Ordinarily this wouldn't be too much of an issue, but I'm trying to force invalid input to be rejected before it even gets into Angular. The way I've resorted to going about doing this is by making the number input hidden, and showing the valid input behind it, so that it appears like they're typing and can only type valid input. This works great until they type a `.`, then the number just vanishes, and returns when they continue.

Is there a way of getting the value out of a HTML 5 `number` type input whilst there's a `.` with no values following it?

If not, is there a way of rejecting the input before it makes it into Angular (on keydown, preventDefault does not work because there's no reliable way of getting the full current input in a `number` type field)?

Answer (score 1):

If that is the behavior you want you should implement [custom vaildation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) where you check the input and allowing dots while the element is chosen, and leaving the element will trigger the validation.

My own opinion, though might be irrelevant, is its OK to show error in validation when the user enters `123.` and then remove it when he continues to type, but thats just me.

Comment: That'd be fine, but the requirement is that it flat out doesn't let you type invalid values (i.e. if you press a button, and it's going to be an invalid result then it just does nothing). I can get this working perfectly if it's a text field, because the current value is always present in the input.

Comment: So why not make it a regular text field and implement your own validation? Disallow regular characters, allow only numbers and a single dot. You can build a regex for it.

Comment: That's what the compromise currently is, but then you get a normal keyboard when looking at the app (this is a hybrid app, as mentioned) - it's not great UX, and really should show the numeric keypad. And before it is suggested, we can't use tel, or the iOS number keyboard input pattern because the keyboard needs to have a `.` to put in decimal points.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to prevent any input being assigned to a model on user input, you can expose the event object by explicitly passing it to the method you are assigning to an `ng-keydown` in your template. In this case I would create a method that accepts the event object and the scoped model on the input field itself, then checks if the input is indeed desirable. If it is, then assign the value to the model that needs to update.

```
<!-- template -->
<input <input ng-model="testValue" ng-keydown="validateValue($event, value)">
```

and the in your controller on $scope

```
//in the controller
    $scope.testValue = '';
    $scope.modelToAssignValue = '';

    $scope.validateValue = function($evt, value) {
     if (($evt.keyCode >= 48 && $evt.keyCode <= 57) ||
        ($evt.keyCode >= 96 && $evt.keyCode <= 105) || 
          ($evt.keyCode = 190)) {
     $scope.modelToAssignValue = value;
     }
    };
```

Comment: This would be fine, but it needs to validate the entire value - not just the current character being input. Otherwise, 123.456.789.012 would be let through for instance. I have a working solution for this with a text input, but it relies on being able to get the current cursor position - another thing you can't do with HTML5 number inputs.